# Potential issues during mongoDB live sync

Tags: mongodb

I have to upgrade mongodb from version 3.4 to 4.2.

It's a replica set.

Instead of upgrading the 3.4 instance itself, we've created a new 4.2 instance and are syncing data to it from the 3.4 version.

Then we will change the connection strings of the client applications to point to the 4.2 mongo.

Are there any issues doing this for a busy application?

Comment: Define "syncing". Do you do on live db or during a maintenance window with exclusive access?

Comment: They're both live DBs but the new one has no client connections yet. They're not in maintenance mode.

Comment: Then, you should be concerned about data consistency during syncing and switchover.

Comment: Yes, I tested this setup in our dev environment and while the live syncing is instantaneous, I am concerned that during the switchover, there may be some data that fails to get synced in a busy application such as the prod application. I do not know how to avoid this though..

Comment: BTW, this is the syncing service being used: https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/data-transmission-service

Comment: hmm, if you are using a paid-for data migration service, data integrity guarantees should be on SLA level. Focus on how to validate it and evidence data loss, if any.

Comment: Yes, sounds good. We'll notify users of an ongoing maintenance when we do the switchover on the prod app so hopefully they won't do any tasks in that period.